# IntelliJ, JInput and the java.library.path

Tags: java, jna, jogl, jinput

I'm working on a java project that uses both Jogl and JInput, and I working in IntelliJ.  I'm having some issues with the application not being able to find various DLLs.   I know the recommended way is to extract the DLLs to a folder and then point the java.library.path at that folder.  Is there a way to include those libraries in project configuration somehow?  I'm pulling those files from jCenter, and I'd rather just point the jar files and let JNA do its work.

Comment: Which version of JOGL do you use? JOGL itself doesn't use JNA, it uses GlueGen (which relies on JNI). I advise you to use jogamp-fat.jar if you really want a very easy solution (despite the few limitations). If you're in a very constrained environment, I fear that you'll have to use java.library.path and to disable the automatic native library loading (see the JOGL user's guide).

Answer (score 0):

I use this method below to set the path dynamically just before the DLL is needed by some object. It is called as follows:

```
setDllLibraryPath("C:/yourPathToDLLs")
```

Method to set library path

```
public static void setDllLibraryPath(String resourceStr) {
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", resourceStr);

        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
        fieldSysPath.set(null, null);//next time path is accessed, the new path will be imported
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```